# How do I exclude a song from iTunes Match

Tags: itunes-match

I have a number of audio files in iTunes that I do NOT want iTunes match to match. I do not want iTunes match to find the files and upload them to the cloud.

Essentially I want to tag some files in iTunes to make them ineligible. How do I do that?

Comment: Are that files music? Maybe you can put them in an category (like audiobooks) which will not be synchronized with iTunes Match!

Comment: Per your comment on Dean's answer: Select the audiobook tracks/files, right click, Get Info, Options Tab, Kind -> Audiobook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with a single library, iTunes match will check everything in your library, under the 25,000 track limit, to try and match.

One possible alternative would be a separate iTunes library for the files you don't want to match.

This separate library could also contain the actual files that have been matched by the other library as well but not be enabled for iTunes match itself.

You could then use this 'super' library as the main one running the iTunes match library occasionally just to keep iTunes match up to date.

[How to run multiple libraries](http://www.apple.com/itunes/inside-itunes/2011/01/keeping-multiple-itunes-libraries-on-a-single-computerif-you-share-your-computer-with-others-and-you.html)

Comment: Whoa. That sounds like a lot to maintain over the long run. There is no way my wife would do that. There has got to be some what to tag a file as audio book or something.